# Using a dynamic list in ELT

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Using MySQL version 5.7.12

Getting an error trying the following:

```
SELECT ELT(
    3,
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS IDs FROM user_table a WHERE IsActive 
) AS IDs
```

Where the 3 in the first spot I can make it random eventually but the IDs from the user_table will be dynamic. Any idea on how I can make this work? Seems like ELT is kind of useless if I have to use it like:

```
SELECT ELT(4,'this','is','the','elt');
```

Just be sure, the following code works:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS IDs FROM user_table a WHERE IsActive
```

which returns 3,4,6,7 as does:

```
SELECT ELT(3,3,4,6,7 ) AS IDs
```

which returns 6

Comment: Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to extract an element from a comma-separated string.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? It looks like you want a random id out of the active users, is that what you want?

Comment: There's no reason to `GROUP_CONCAT` them in the first place. Just use `SELECT id FROM user_table WHERE isActive LIMIT 3, 1`

Comment: Do you mean like this `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SELECT QUOTE(GROUP_CONCAT(id)) FROM user_table WHERE IsActive,',',3)`? This isn't working either.

Comment: yes this is actually part of a larger query. I need a random user that isn't the current user for an event.

Comment: I figured out a different way, this seems to work over all for me. Thanks for the help all! 
`SELECT NB2.event_id 
  , NB2.normalized_by
  FROM (
  SELECT NBi.event_id 
    , ANNOi.id AS normalized_by 
    FROM events NBi
   CROSS JOIN user_table ANNOi
   WHERE NBi.batch = 27
     AND ANNOi.IsActive 
     AND NBi.normalized_by <> ANNOi.id 
   ORDER BY RAND()
  ) NB2
 GROUP BY NB2.event_id
 ORDER BY RAND()
 LIMIT 795;`

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the point for aggregating just to select a single value.

Also, since there is no `order by` option to your `group_concat()`, you actually get `id`s in an *undefined* ordering, which makes the final `id` that will be selected also undefined (meaning: two consecutive executions of the same query might, or might not, give different results).

If you want a (well-defined) `id` out of the list of active users, you can do a regular `select` statement, with `order by` and `limit`:

```
select id
from user_table
where isActive
order by id
limit 3, 1
```

This gives you the `id` of the third active user in the table, ordered by `id`.

If you want a random `id` out of active users (which is not the same thing as *undefined*), then:

```
select id
from user_table
where isActive
order by rand()
limit 1
```